# unable to open old email items (pst file)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Just before switching to gmail as my mail server, I did an export of my mailbox. Now I need to access some old mails and open my outlook 2013 (I still like this version the most). When I open my old pst file, it's inbox is empty, and I now have a new folder with about 2000 items called Sync Issues and a subfolder for that one called "Local Failures (This Computer only)"

Any suggestions to how I can access my old mails?

Comment: It should be as simple as adding the archive .PST file to your Outlook profile.

Comment: exactly Ramhound and I have done it plenty of times before with other pst files. But this time instead of showing all my old emails, it just list everything as sync issues.

Comment: Was the old mail server running Exchange?  This .PST had permanent copies of the emails from the old mail server?  It's almost like you get the correct .PST file.

Comment: First, check the size of the PST - it should be a large size. Search for the program 'scanpst.exe' and run that on the file to repair the index

Comment: Have you ever checked your old .pst file before? Were you able to successfully see the emails after the export operation? According to your description, looks like those emails had not been successfully exported to this specific pst file. As I know, the Export operation from Outlook will not affect the storage of the emails themselves on the server side. Any possibility to recover emails from your old mail server?

Comment: @ramhound, no just a normal pop3 server.
JohnnyVegas good suggestion, it found some minor issues but it didn't fix the problem.
Jeff yes got a few even older pst files from the same server, they worked fine, and can't recover from mail server as it's been closed down.

Comment: Seems trying to recover emails from .pst files as much as possible using repair tools has become the only workaround now.

Comment: a pity, but your are most likely right Jeff. I don't think this is a common issue.

Comment: Comparing with back up mailbox items via .pst files, I would be more willing to use Online Archive features to store old mailbox items online, so that we could avoid issues about corrupted .pst files. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-archiving-service-description/archive-features

Comment: Great suggestion @JeffYang7

Comment: its my pleasure:)